# make magento custom attribute filterable

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way to make a custom magento product attribute filterable through a setup file and resource file?

I can create the attribute, I can even set the group it goes into but w/out manually going into the admin and adjusting the filterable option on the attribute, I can't get it to be set to filterable (especially filterable - I've tried w/ true/false and 0,1,2). I've tried adjust about every option that makes sense.

ie:

```
app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Setup.php
public function getDefaultEntities()
{
    return array(
            'catalog_product' => array(
                'entity_model'      => 'catalog/product',
                'attribute_model'   => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
                'table'             => 'catalog/product',
                'additional_attribute_table' => 'catalog/eav_attribute',
                'entity_attribute_collection' => 'catalog/product_attribute
                'attributes' => array(
                    'attribute_name' => array(
                        'group'                      => 'Attribute Set Group',
                        'type'                       => 'int',
                        'backend'                    => '',
                        'frontend'                   => '',
                        'label'                      => 'Attribute Label',
                        'input'                      => 'select',
                        'class'                      => '',
                        'source'                     => 'eav/entity_attribu
                        'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_
                        'visible'                    => true,
                        'required'                   => false,
                        'user_defined'               => true,
                        'default'                    => false,
                        'searchable'                 => true,
                        'filterable'                 => 1,
                        'comparable'                 => false,
                        'visible_on_front'           => true,
                        'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
                        'used_in_product_listing'    => true,
                        'used_for_sort_by'           => true,
                        'unique'                     => false,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
}


app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/sql/module_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
$this->installEntities();
```

Comment: Should there be an `option` key to make this attribute use a Multiple Select?

Comment: And just to be sure, cleared caches and rebuilt indexes after creation?

Comment: don't need the `option` tag - its not a multi select, and I've cleared caches and reindexed whats needed.  however, I can guarantee the index is not the issue to make it filterable.  when I run my update the attribute setup as is leaves the `catalog_eav_attribute` table record w/ `is_filterable = 0`.  to fix this I need to add `$this->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_name', 'is_fiterable', 1);` to my resource file.  Now I'm just curious if I can do this in the Setup.php file or not?  It feels like adjusting the filterable option should work.

Comment: Afaik layered navigation filters **must** be of input type Dropdown, Multiple Select or Price. That's why I asked for the `option` key.

Comment: Found the link stating that: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work/

Comment: I see what you're saying, we're talking about the same thing.  the input type Dropdown = select.  so in my Setup.php file, for the attribute option `input` I have a Dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an attribute in the following way:

```
module_name\sql\machinesearch_setup
```

Create one SQL setup file like this in your module.

```
<?php
    $installer = $this;
    $data= array (
        'attribute_set' =>  'Default',
        'global'    =>  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'label'     => 'Year',
        'input'     => 'multiselect',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'default_value_text' => 'varchar',
        'unique'    => false,
        'required'  => false,
        'visible'   => true,
        'searchable'=> true,
        'visible_in_advanced_search'    => true,
        'html_allowed_on_front'         => true,
        'comparable'   => false,  
        'backend_type'  => 'varchar',
        'backend'   => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
        'group'     => 'General',
        'user_defined'  => true,
       );

       $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','mmy_year',$data);


       $data= array 
        (  
        'attribute_set' =>  'Default',
        'global'  => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'label' => 'Make',
        'input' => 'multiselect',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'default_value_text'  => 'varchar',
        'unique'=> false,
        'required'=> false,
        'visible' => true,
        'searchable'=> true,
        'visible_in_advanced_search'=> true,
        'html_allowed_on_front'  => true,
        'comparable'=> false,
        'backend_type'  => 'varchar',
        'backend'=> 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
        'group'  => 'General',
        'user_defined'=> true,
        );    
        $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','mmy_make',$data);
    $data= array (
          'attribute_set'               =>  'Default',
          'global'                          =>  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
          'label'                           => 'Model',
          'input'                           => 'multiselect',
          'type'                            => 'text',
          'default_value_text'            => 'varchar',
          'unique'                          => false,
          'required'                    => false,
          'visible'                     => true,
          'searchable'                  => true,
          'visible_in_advanced_search'  => true,
          'html_allowed_on_front'       => true,
          'comparable'                  => false,
          'backend_type'                  => 'varchar',
          'backend'                     => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
          'group'                           => 'General',
          'user_defined'                    => true,
          );

  $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','mmy_model',$data);
  $installer->endSetup();
?>
```